# Google I'm feeling lucky button animation javascript

Tags: javascript, css-animations, mousehover

Google I'm feeling lucky button, changes when you hover over it. how is it done using java scripts, I think there is a DIV change there am I right? Or is it CSS animation? I haven't found a similar example anywhere.

Comment: There are lots of ways it could be done.

Comment: My guess is it's Javascript animation. It picks a random item from the array of labels. Then it goes into a loop, changing the label to the next item in the array until it gets to the chosen one, and using animation for the transitions.

Answer (score -2):

Its a CSS style, and can be achieved by adding something similar to this:-

```
#lucky:hover {box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 3px 3px 0px 0px;}
```

Comment: That's not the effect he's asking about. I think he's talking about the slot-machine style animation of the text in the button.

Comment: If you get rude you get more downvotes. Be more polite please. I wont downvote you as far as OPs question is really broad, but the answer should be closed because its to broad anyway. By the way if you are not sure about the question then tell the OP in comments first that he should be more specific, thanks.

Comment: @DatRid, totally man, I'm really fed up with the community though. I asked a question the other day and I was nailed by down-votes, for no reason. Goodbye reputation. Goodbye the privilege to ask any more questions. So today I was just trying to help, get some reputation back. Unlikely!